# PHP: DomDocument & XPath - how to select empty elements?

Tags: php, xpath

Assume the following tree:

```
<root>
 <a></a>
 <b>  </b>
 <c>
 </c>
 <d>Hello world</d>
 <e><f>!!!</f></e>
</root>
```

I need to be able to select all empty tags, so `a`, `b`, and `c` in the above example. In my scenario, I consider `b` and `c` as being empty, despite them having white spaces.

Further, I would not consider `e` as being empty as it has a child.

**How do I select all elements that do no have a child, whose text node is completely empty or comprises only of white spaces?**

The following XPath would select `a`, but miss `b` and `c`:

```
`.//*[not(text())`]
```

My feeling is that I need to use `normalize-space()` somehow, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with XPath1 you gonna need `normalize-space`. Try this:

`.//*[not(*)][not(normalize-space(text()))]`

Comment: As it turns out, I do not want to delete all empty tags. Some tags are going to be exempt from this. How would I except, for example, all `foo` and `bar` tags?

Comment: Add more conditions like `.//*[not(*)][not(normalize-space(text()))][not(name()='foo')][not(name()='bar')]`